# how to set var in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

How to use the below variable

```
SET DESKTOP_PATH = C:\Users\Kostas\Desktop\ToMobile
SET MOBILE_PATH = H:\koinoxrista
```

in xcopy command?

I use the below code

```
xcopy %DESKTOP_PATH%\*.txt %MOBILE_PATH% /v
```

but i receive

```
file not found - *.txt
```

here is my code

```
    @echo off

SET DESKTOP_PATH = C:\Users\Kostas\Desktop\ToMobile
SET MOBILE_PATH = H:\koinoxrista

chdir \
chdir /d h:\koinoxrista

SET "FLAG="

IF EXIST Bill.txt SET FLAG=1
IF EXIST BillPayments.txt SET FLAG=1
IF EXIST Collector.txt SET FLAG=1
IF EXIST CompanyInfo.txt  SET FLAG=1
IF EXIST Expense.txt  SET FLAG=1
IF EXIST ExpensePayments.txt  SET FLAG=1
IF EXIST FlatComments.txt  SET FLAG=1
IF EXIST FlatMetric.txt  SET FLAG=1

IF DEFINED FLAG (ECHO Error!) ELSE (xcopy %DESKTOP_PATH%\*.txt %MOBILE_PATH% /v /w)

pause
```

Comment: Is that the actual path in your `DESKTOP_PATH` variable, or do you have spaces in your `DESKTOP_PATH`?

Comment: Please post your actual batch file code, and not just snippets. This can't be it, because you SET `MOBILE_PATH` but use `%MOBILE_DIR%`, which doesn't exist anywhere in what you've posted.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the paths with double quotes? `xcopy "%DESKTOP_PATH%\*.txt" "%MOBILE_PATH%" /V`

Comment: yes I do with no success. Same error

Comment: I might try echoing out your variables, to make sure they are what they think you are: `echo %DESKTOP_PATH%`, etc.

Comment: I Have Just edit my post

Comment: Get rid of the blanks before and after the equal sign.

Comment: Yes this was the problem. Thx

Comment: `SET "FLAG="` looks wrong too. To unset it just do `SET FLAG=`

Comment: @StephenConnolly - No, the quotes as written is the preferred syntax. It protects against hidden spaces or tabs. All characters after the last quote are ignored if the opening quote precedes the variable name. That syntax is also very useful for introducing special characters into the value without escaping, and without quotes being in the actual value.

Comment: @dbenham. Didn't know that! Every day is a schoolday:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the spaces in SET command

```
SET DESKTOP_PATH=C:\Users\Kostas\Desktop\ToMobile
SET MOBILE_PATH=H:\koinoxrista
```